# Set Google Chrome's disable-web-security flag in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Running my application in chrome gives me the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/Nancy/Nancy_16Jul/Nancy.Rest.Client/Assets/Templates/Login.htm. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

If I run the application by disabling the web security it works fine. But I want to set the web security through code. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: This cannot be set via JavaScript.  Imagine the security risks that could happen if it could be.

Comment: Wouldn't be much of a security feature if a web page could just disable it, would it?

Answer (score 1):

No, of course not. If a site could just turn off web security, that'd make the security pretty worthless!